# Firebase push notification adding action buttons

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notifications on server side and I am using this http protocol(https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) and I want to add action buttons like this in issue https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1484.
This is my request body

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "secret"
  ],
  "notification": {
    "title": "New Article",
    "body": "Article content",
    "sound": "default",
    "actions": [
      {
        "action": "like-button",
        "title": "Like",
        "url": "https://example.com"
      },
      {
        "action": "read-more-button",
        "title": "Read more",
        "url": "https://example.com"
      }
    ],
    "click_action": "read-more-button"
  },
  "data": {
    "id": "some uuid",
  }
}
```

I tried this but nothing show up. How can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FCM doesn't support this functionality right now. The solution would be to send a data message via FCM and create your own notification.

1. Send data message with your own key-value pairs:

```
  "data": {
    "key": "value",
    "key2": "value2"
  }
```

2. Receive messages, use a service that extends `FirebaseMessagingService`.
3. Override the `onMessageReceived` callback to create notification based on your data message.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: Thanks, we just wondering if any other solution would exist. But we solve like this because there is no way adding buttons in fcm side.

Comment: afaik, using data message is the only solution

Comment: The only problem is that when sending only data, there is no background handler for the messages.  In the foreground, the push is received and can be handled with a local notification but in the background there is nothing.

Comment: Then what we have found out for background notification?  any idea guys ?

Comment: You should be able to receive data messages in both the background and foreground. If the message will trigger a notification, be sure to set its priority to high